# how do I perform healthchecks on clamav using docker

Tags: docker, clamav

I am deploying on AWS  [clamav](https://github.com/mko-x/docker-clamav)

whos Dockerfile is :

```
FROM alpine:3.14
LABEL maintainer="Markus Kosmal <code@m-ko.de>"

RUN apk add --no-cache bash clamav clamav-daemon clamav-libunrar

COPY conf /etc/clamav
COPY bootstrap.sh /
COPY envconfig.sh /
COPY check.sh /



RUN mkdir /var/run/clamav && \
    chown clamav:clamav /var/run/clamav && \
    chmod 750 /var/run/clamav && \
    chown -R clamav:clamav bootstrap.sh check.sh /etc/clamav && \
    chmod u+x bootstrap.sh check.sh 

EXPOSE 3310/tcp

USER clamav

CMD ["/bootstrap.sh"]
```

and since I am using a mirror I am testing locally using a docker-compose file

```
version: "3.7"

services:
   mirror:
     build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: mirror/Dockerfile

     ports:
        - "8080:8080"

  clamav:
    build:
      context: ../clamav
    environment:
      
       
      CLAMAVDATABASEMIRROR: "http://0.0.0.0:8080"
    
    depends_on:
       - mirror
    ports:
     - "3310:3310"
```

services work fine and when I run `docker-compose up --build` I can see from the logs that the services is pulling the daily update and stuff.

if I run `docker container ls`

I get that `clamav` has ports: 3310/tcp wheras the mirror has a mapped port on my local host

0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp

and I can run `curl localhost:8080`

But If I try and curl localhost on 3310 I get

`curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

now: how do I perform a healthcheck on the `clamav` service?

Comment: docker service inspect clamav

Comment: docker inspect provides details on the container. I would like to have something like `curl -I localhost:8080` but as I wrote if I perform `curl -I localhost:3310` it fails

Comment: You haven't published any `ports:` for the other service, so it won't be accessible from outside Docker space.

Comment: sorry.. I edited the docker-compose.. publishing ports changes nothing I am afraid.